How do I link libvlc.dylib and libvlccore.dylib on arm64 MacOS to create a decoder module for VLC?
I am trying to create a decoder module for VLC, and in order to create the final shared library, I need to access functions which are defined in libvlc.dylib and libvlccore.dylib. However, when I try linking my object file with VLC libraries, I get this error:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_block_Release", referenced from:
      _Decode in my_decoder.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is the linking command I am running:
g++ my_decoder.o -L/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib -lvlc -lvlccore -dynamiclib -o libmy_decoder.dylib
And this is the contents of my_decoder.c:
#include <vlc_common.h>
#include <vlc_plugin.h>
#include <vlc_codec.h>

#define MODULE_STRING "My Decoder"

vlc_module_begin()
        /*
         * Module details
         * Set capability and function callbacks
         */
vlc_module_end()

static int Open(vlc_object_t *p_this) {

        /*
         * Create the decoder
         * Set pf_decode = Decode;
         */

        return VLCDEC_SUCCESS;

}

static int Decode(decoder_t *p_dec, block_t *p_block) {

        /*    
         * Decode the data in p_block, and create p_pic
         */

        // decoder_QueueVideo does not produce linking errors
        decoder_QueueVideo(p_dec, &p_pic);
        // block_Release cannot be identified by linker
        block_Release(p_block);

        return VLCDEC_SUCCESS;

}

static int Close(vlc_object_t *p_this) {

        /*
         * Close the decoder
         */

        return VLC_SUCCESS;

}

I compile my_decoder.c with this command:
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/path/to/vlc/header/files/ -g -Wall -fPIC my_decoder.c -c -o my_decoder.o
Notes:

I downloaded the precompiled version of VLC for MacOS Universal Binaries
VLC version 3.0.21
I am able to accomplish all of these steps on Ubuntu with no issues, which leads me to believe the issue is with MacOS or arm64/x86 architecture discrepancies


The VLC application does not include those header files or those libraries, so you would need to use an alternative source for those files.

@trojanfoe I cloned the VLC source code to get the header files, but is there a reason I cannot use the vlc and vlccore libraries found in '/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib'? Would I then have to compile VLC from the source code to obtain the correct libraries?

No that’s fine but I think the plugin library is missing.

Did you check if we stripped the symbols from the distributed libraries?
